# Magento 2 : Custom quote column value not copied on quote merge

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, quote, magento-2.1.8

I have created a custom column named 'campaign_id' through UpgradeSchema in quote table as below.

```
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
     $installer->getTable('quote'),
     'campaign_id',
     [
         'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
         'length' => 11,
         'nullable' => false,
         'comment' => 'Campaign ID'
     ]
);
```

I am setting its value through custom controller on add to cart as below

```
// \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session

$this->checkoutSession->getQuote()
     ->setCampaignId($campaign_id)
     ->save();
```

The value is getting saved properly when I'm adding product as a guest user or as a logged in user.

However when I add the product as a guest user and then log in, the custom quote column value from guest quote is not getting copied to customer quote on quote merge.

Answer (score 3):

I did it using the sales_quote_merge_after event

events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_quote_merge_after">
        <observer name="sales_quote_merge_custom_column" instance="Namespace\Module\Observer\SalesQuoteMergeAfter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

SalesQuoteMergeAfter.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SalesQuoteMergeAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $guestQuote = $observer->getEvent()->getSource();   //before merge
        $customerQuote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote(); //after merge

        if($guestQuote->getCampaignBlockId()) {
            $customerQuote->setCampaignBlockId($guestQuote->getCampaignBlockId());
        }
    }
}
```