# Magento 2 can not find sales_quote_merge_after event

Tags: magento2

**Magento 2** i can not find `sales_quote_merge_after` event for merge cart.

anyone have idea ?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/224333/magento-2-custom-quote-column-value-not-copied-on-quote-merge

Answer (score 2):

You can find it in `vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote.php` file under below function.

```
/**
 * Merge quotes
 *
 * @param   Quote $quote
 * @return $this
 */
public function merge(Quote $quote)
{
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
        $this->_eventPrefix . '_merge_before',
        [$this->_eventObject => $this, 'source' => $quote]
    );

    foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
        $found = false;
        foreach ($this->getAllItems() as $quoteItem) {
            if ($quoteItem->compare($item)) {
                $quoteItem->setQty($quoteItem->getQty() + $item->getQty());
                $this->itemProcessor->merge($item, $quoteItem);
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!$found) {
            $newItem = clone $item;
            $this->addItem($newItem);
            if ($item->getHasChildren()) {
                foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                    $newChild = clone $child;
                    $newChild->setParentItem($newItem);
                    $this->addItem($newChild);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Init shipping and billing address if quote is new
     */
    if (!$this->getId()) {
        $this->getShippingAddress();
        $this->getBillingAddress();
    }

    if ($quote->getCouponCode()) {
        $this->setCouponCode($quote->getCouponCode());
    }

    $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
        $this->_eventPrefix . '_merge_after',
        [$this->_eventObject => $this, 'source' => $quote]
    );

    return $this;
}
```